# Change incoming bluetooth packets

Tags: linux, bluetooth, iptables, netfilter

I want to change incoming Bluetooth packets before they are handled by the system. Something like netfiler_queue would be ideal, however it doesn't seem to work.
Running the following python code:

```
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    print(pkt)
    pkt.accept()
nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1, print_and_accept)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('')
```

With the iptables rule:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i bluetooth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

Doesn't print any bluetooth packets (which I can see with tcpdump on bluetooth0). The python code seems to work for IP packets when I change the iptables rule to be on the lo interface.

Can I change the iptables rule to make it work? Or is there any other way to do what I want?